# groupingBy a join in KTORM

Tags: ktorm

I want to join a  N x M relation, returning all N, and a count of how many M are there:

```
SELECT N.*, COUNT(M.id) FROM N LEFT JOIN M ON N.id = M.n_id GROUP BY N.id
```

but I don't see how.  Joining and aggregation seem to exclude each other, or are not implemented, or not documented (or I didn't find it).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I asked ChatGPT, and it gave enough hits, so that I could actually do this.

```
val resultSet = database.from(N)
    .leftJoin(right = M, on = N.id eq M.nId)
    .select(N.columns + count(M.id))
    .groupBy(N.id)
```

Referencing the `count` column is a bit more tricky:

```
val countColumn = ColumnDeclaringExpression(
     expression = count(),
     declaredName = "count",
     sqlType = IntSqlType,
     isLeafNode = false,
     extraProperties = mapOf()
   )

resultSet.map{ it[countColumn] } // for each row, this returns the count
```

hope it helps someone!